# Finding the maximum of $\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{d}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{d}{b}$

Tags: inequality, optimization

If $a,b,c,d$ are **distinct** real numbers such that $\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{d}+\dfrac{d}{a}=4$ and $ac=bd$.

Then how would we calculate the maximum value of $$\dfrac{a}{c}+\dfrac{b}{d}+\dfrac{c}{a}+\dfrac{d}{b}.$$

I was unable to proceed due to the **'distinct'**.

Comment: I don't know about these `:(` I'm a high school student.

Comment: Next time, please just edit the parts that you do not agree on, instead of rolling back everything. And don't use `\dfrac` in titles when it's not necessary.

Comment: Do **not** engage in rollback wars. I'm locking this question for one hour. Please chill a bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since both conditions and the expression to be maximised are homogeneous, we can WLOG assume $|abcd|=1$. (If $|abcd|=k$, then replace $a, b, c, d$ with $\frac{a}{\sqrt[4]{k}}, \frac{b}{\sqrt[4]{k}}, \frac{c}{\sqrt[4]{k}}, \frac{d}{\sqrt[4]{k}}$) Thus $1=|abcd|=|ac||bd|=|ac|^2$, so $ac=bd=\pm 1$.

Since $ac=bd$, $\frac{c}{d}=\frac{b}{a}$ and $\frac{d}{a}=\frac{c}{b}$. We have $$0=(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}-2)+(\frac{b}{c}+\frac{d}{a}-2)=(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}-2)+(\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{b}-2)=\frac{(a-b)^2}{ab}+\frac{(b-c)^2}{bc}$$

Thus $0=c(a-b)^2+a(b-c)^2$, so $0=ac(a-b)^2+a^2(b-c)^2=ac(a-b)^2+(ab-ac)^2$. If $ac=1$, then $0=(a-b)^2+(ab-1)^2$ so $a=b$, contradicting the fact that $a, b, c, d$ are distinct.

Therefore $ac=-1=bd$, so $0=-(a-b)^2+(ab+1)^2$, so $ab+1=\pm (a-b)$.

The expression which is to be maximised becomes $$\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{d}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{d}{b}=\frac{a^2+c^2}{ac}+\frac{b^2+d^2}{bd}=-(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)=-(a^2+b^2+\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2})$$

Notice that this expression is symmetric with respect to $a, b$, so we can WLOG assume that $a-b$ has the same sign as $ab+1$, so $a-b=ab+1$, giving $(a+1)(b-1)=-2$, so $b=1-\frac{2}{a+1}=\frac{a-1}{a+1}$. It now suffices to maximise the expression

$$-(a^2+\frac{(a-1)^2}{(a+1)^2}+\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{(a+1)^2}{(a-1)^2})$$

In fact, I shall prove that this expression has maximum value $-12$. Indeed,

\begin{align}
& -(a^2+\frac{(a-1)^2}{(a+1)^2}+\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{(a+1)^2}{(a-1)^2}) \leq -12 \\
\Leftrightarrow & a^2+\frac{(a-1)^2}{(a+1)^2}+\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{(a+1)^2}{(a-1)^2} \geq 12 \\
\Leftrightarrow & (a^2-12)(a^2)(a+1)^2(a-1)^2+(a-1)^4a^2+(a+1)^2(a-1)^2+(a+1)^4a^2 \geq 0 \\
\Leftrightarrow & (a^2-2a-1)^2(a^2+2a-1)^2 \geq 0
\end{align}

The last inequality is obviously true. Now, we have equality when $a=1+\sqrt{2}, b=-1+\sqrt{2}, c=1-\sqrt{2}, d=-1-\sqrt{2}$. Therefore the maximum value is $-12$.

**Edit:** In my answer above, it gives the impression that $-12$ appeared magically. I shall provide the motivation for getting this value below. Note that the following may not necessarily be rigorous.

**Motivation**

Let's suppose that the maximum value is $-c$. (Note that the maximum value is negative, hence the use of $-c$ instead of $c$, since I prefer to work with positive $c$) Let's put this into the equation.

\begin{align}
& -(a^2+\frac{(a-1)^2}{(a+1)^2}+\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{(a+1)^2}{(a-1)^2}) \leq -c \\
\Leftrightarrow & a^2+\frac{(a-1)^2}{(a+1)^2}+\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{(a+1)^2}{(a-1)^2} \geq c \\
\Leftrightarrow & (a^2-c)(a^2)(a+1)^2(a-1)^2+(a-1)^4a^2+(a+1)^2(a-1)^2+(a+1)^4a^2 \geq 0 \\
\Leftrightarrow & a^8-ca^6+(14+2c)a^4-ca^2+1 \geq 0
\end{align}

Intuitively, we know that if $a$ is a root of the degree 8 polynomial, $b, c, d$ should also be roots. Furthermore, we would want the polynomial to factorise as a square of a polynomial, so that it is clearly always non-negative. As such, the polynomial should have 4 distinct roots, each with multiplicity $2$.

Let us put $a^8-ca^6+(14+2c)a^4-ca^2+1=(a^4+pa^2+q)^2$ (It is intuitive that we can ignore all terms with odd degree) Comparing coefficient of $a^6$ gives $p=-\frac{c}{2}$, and comparing coefficient of $a^2$ gives $-c=2pq=-cq$, so $q=1$. Comparing coefficient of $a^4$ gives $14+2c=p^2+2q=\frac{c^2}{4}+2$, so $0=c^2-8c-48=(c-12)(c+4)$. We want $c$ to be positive, so let's choose $c=12$.

Now, we already have done part of the factorisation: $a^8-12a^6+38a^4-12a^2+1=(a^4-6a^2+1)^2$. In fact, at this point, we already can prove that $-12$ is indeed an upper bound. However, we also want to find an equality case, to confirm that the maximum is indeed attainable. To do this, we complete the factorisation, by noting that $a^4-6a^2+1=(a^2-1)^2-4a^2=(a^2-2a-1)(a^2+2a-1)$. This easily leads to the equality case $a=1+\sqrt{2}, b=-1+\sqrt{2}, c=1-\sqrt{2}, d=-1-\sqrt{2}$ (unique up to cycling of the elements)

Comment: how did you know the max of the expression is -12? It seems your last step is not quite correct..

Comment: @Easy which step? I will add motivation for how I obtained $-12$ in a moment.

Comment: from the bottom 4th line to 3rd line, the above one has constant term -11, but the latter one has constant term 1. Maybe you'd better explain what made you think of 12, since you were proving, but not explaining.

Comment: @Easy it is correct. Perhaps you didn't see the $a^2$ term in $(a^2-12)(a^2)(a+1)^2(a-1)^2$?

Answer (score 4):

Let $w=\frac{a}{b}$, $x=\frac{b}{c}$, $y=\frac{c}{d}$, $z=\frac{d}{a}$. Then 
$$\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{d}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{d}{b}=wx+xy+yz+zw=(x+z)(w+y)\leqslant\Bigl(\frac{w+x+y+z}{2}\Bigr)^2$$

Comment: @exploringnet the answer should be negative.

Comment: @IvanLoh???????? How? $D\leq2^2$ according to this answer so the max would be 4.

Comment: @exploringnet No. This answer is wrong. $4$ is not attainable, because it would imply that $a, b, c, d$ **are not distinct**.

Comment: @exploringnet Whenever you are trying to determine the maximum of an expression, even though you have proved an upper bound, the upper bound may not actually be the maximum, because it is unattainable. In this case, for equality to hold, one would require $x+z=w+y$, which in turn implies that $(a-c)(b-d)=0$, contradicting the fact that $a, b, c, d$ are **distinct**.

Comment: @Easy And what about $ac=bd$

Comment: @Easy The inequality is indeed correct, but equality cannot be attained, so this does not give the maximum value.

Comment: @IvanLoh Please add your solution .

Comment: @exploringnet, if I were using that inequality, the equal sign holds if and only if $x+z=w+y=0$, which will be not possible.

Comment: @exploringnet I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $d=\frac{ac}{b}$ the constraint becomes
$$\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right)+\left(\frac{c}{b}+\frac{b}{c}\right)=4$$
while the function to be maximized becomes
$$\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b^2}{ac}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{ac}{b^2}=\frac{b}{c}\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right)+\frac{c}{b}\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right)=\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right)\left(\frac bc+\frac cb\right).$$
Now set
$$x=\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\qquad \mathrm{and}\qquad y=\frac bc+\frac cb$$
so that $x+y=4$ and we want to maximize $xy$. Observe that if $x$ is positive then $a$ and $b$ have the same sign and thus
$$x=\frac ab+\frac ba=\frac{(a-b)^2}{ab}+2>2$$
because $a$ and $b$ are distinct. The same clearly also holds for $y$.

But then $x$ and $y$ must have opposite signs: they can not be both negative because $x+y=4$, and they can not be both positive because the sum would be strictly greater than $4$. Suppose for example that $x<0$, then
$$x=\frac ab+\frac ba=\frac{(a+b)^2}{ab}-2\leq -2$$
because $a$ and $b$ have opposite signs. Therefore $y=4-x\geq 6$ which implies $xy\leq -12$. Putting wlog $b=1$ and solving for the equality cases we obtain the equations
$$a+\frac 1a=-2\qquad\mathrm{and}\qquad c+\frac1c=6$$
which have solutions and so the upper bound $-12$ is attained.